# Bucle para hacer 3 acciones idénticas con 3 objetos distintos: motor1.setRegister(0x00) motor2.setRegister(0x00) motor3.setRegister(0x00)

Tags: python, bucles, diccionarios

En vez de:

```
motor1.setRegister(0x00)
motor2.setRegister(0x00)
motor3.setRegister(0x00)
```

Quisiera hacer algo así:

```
motor = ["motor1", "motor2", "motor3"]

for i in motor:

    motor[i].setRegister(0x00)
```

Sin embargo, me da un error al compilar (AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'setRegister'). Alguna solución?

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: no conozco python pero te voy a dejar un comentario basado en javascript jaja: todo parece indicar que cuando le aplicas `setRegister` a `motor[i]` le estas queriendo aplicar la funcion `setRegister` a un string, mientras que antes cuando aplicababas `.setRegister` al principio lo hacias en un objeto declarado como motor1. Supongo que en tu array tenes que guardar objetos en lugar de strings, y asi deberia funcionar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

En tu primer ejemplo:

```
motor1.setRegister(0x00)
motor2.setRegister(0x00)
motor3.setRegister(0x00)
```

Cada uno de los motores fueron primero declarados como instancias de una clase, por ejemplo algo así:

```
motor1 = Motor()
motor2 = Motor()
motor3 = Motor()
```

Si tu lista la hicieras con las instancias (Es decir, con los objetos, como lo comentó @Agustin G.) en lugar de `strings` entonces sí funcionaría.

Pero hay otro error en tu segundo ejemplo, en `Python` cuando haces `for i in motor:` el valor que obtiene `i` al iterar la lista no es un número, sino el elemento de la lista, es decir, el `string`

Mira el siguiente ejemplo:

```
motor = ["motor1", "motor2", "motor3"]

for i in motor:
    print(i)
```

Esto imprime:

```
motor1
motor2
motor3
```

Entonces, regresando al punto de crear una lista e iterar en los elementos para ejecutar un método específico, lo podrías hacer de la siguiente forma:

**Nota:** Ya que no incluiste el código completo cree un código genérico que tendrás que adaptar a tus necesidades.

```
class Motor(object):
    def setRegister(self, s):
        print(s)

# Definir instancias de la clase
motor1 = Motor()
motor2 = Motor()
motor3 = Motor()

# Definir lista de instancias de la clase
motors = [motor1, motor2, motor3]

# Iterar sobre la lista
for m in motors:
    m.setRegister('0x00')
```

Esto imprime:

```
0x00
0x00
0x00
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ha funcionado perfectamente. Un saludo!